# SDK location not found, define location in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment varibale

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I got this error:

```
SDK location not found, define location in the local.properties file 
or with an ANDROID_HOME environment varibale.
```

My SDK is installed at: `C:\Users\Frank\Documents\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk`

When I put that in to `local.properties` I get a error.

I'm using it for a Gradle project.

I've tried a lot of things but nothing works....

Comment: could you paste the content of your local.properties. Or maybe the sdk location has to be defined in the Gradle config.

Comment: I have this in my local.properties: C:\Users\Frank\Documents\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk 

Where can I find the Gradle config?

Comment: I have answered this question here, [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27620262/sdk-location-not-found-define-location-with-sdk-dir-in-the-local-properties-fil/35702596#35702596)